# How to do correlation between likert and binary variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, inference, descriptive-statistics

I want to look at whether socioeconomic status influences students’ self-efficacy in science subjects.

My socioeconomic questions are yes/no questions or choice out of a list of parental occupation

The self-efficacy questions are likert scales (e.g Learning advanced science topics would be easy for me - strongly agree to strongly disagree)

What is the best statistical test to use on SPSS to answer my research question? VERY VERY new to stats.

Answer (score 0):

A possible correlation coefficient would be the [polychoric correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation), which is intended for two ordinal variables. Keep in mind that it assumes that your variables were originally normal (and continuous) and were later discretized - if you cannot take this assumption, don't use it.

As far as I know there is no closed form formula for the polychoric correlation, but an approximation can be found [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/polychoric-correlation/). The method is implemented in [SPSS](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=b6e15a87-ff78-492b-8582-bd5c232ae870&CommunityKey=886b6874-0fb1-402c-8243-c70ef8179a99&tab=digestviewer#bmb6e15a87-ff78-492b-8582-bd5c232ae870), as well as in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/index.html) and [SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/65543/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_details14.htm).